# Ghostscript 9.07: Error: A pdfmark destimation ... points beyond the last page

Tags: latex, ghostscript

I use `gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=$2 -dLastPage=$3 -sOUTPUTFILE=$4 $1` in a script to extract pages from a pdf file with Ghostscript 9.07. I obtain a lot of warnings (as in the first row in the following output) and one error:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.07:    **** Warning: Outline has invalid link that was discarded.    
GPL Ghostscript 9.07: ERROR: A pdfmark destination page 4 points beyond the last page 3.
```

The resulting pdf (consisting of the extracted pages) is fine, however. I am wondering why I obtain this error and the warnings although I chose the option `-q` for `quiet`. I did some search on that and found, for example, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24428/latex-and-pdf-rangecheck-error-in-pdfmark-using-ghostscript), but the pdf file is already generated with `hypertexnames=false` and so the suggested solution there does not work in my case (Ubuntu 13.04).

Just to add: The .pdf file is generated via pdflatex from:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\node at (current page.south)[rectangle, fill, color=gray]{};
\clearpage 
\section{foo}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{bar}
foo bar 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Duplicate posted: [Ghostscript 9.07: Error: A pdfmark destination … points beyond the last page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111057/5764)

Comment: Well, I registered the question for being 'closed' since I realized that this has to do with the way the pdf file is generated and thus relates rather to LaTeX/tex.stackexchange

Comment: To avoid duplication and possible double work from the respective communities, you should flag it for migration, or delete it here before posting it elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original file contains named destinations (in this case the Outline tree) which point to a numbered page which will not be present in the final output file (because you have not chosen to include all the pages).

The destinations are therefore elided, which is why your output file works, and a warning is generated to tell you that some requested destinations will not be present.

The pdfwrite device pretty much ignores -q for these kinds of warnings, as we think they are important.